# Eclipse basic shortcuts - assigning assistant, extract variable

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

There are some pretty basic tasks and I'm in doubt how it can be effectively done in Eclipse IDE:

1. Content assisted variable declaration/assignment:
   Imagine you have to write something like this `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();`. How can it be effectively typed? One guess like `DateFormat df = new`  plus some quick `Ctrl+Space`, not very, very long `SimpleDateFormat`. But this does not work, it will show completely useless alphabetically sorted types from classpath, usually unassignable to `DateFormat`.
2. Extracting variable:
   Is there any way to extract variable like `Alt+Shift+L` does but WITHOUT the need to manipulate the mouse to select expression or whole line? Just like extract content under cursor? Or is there some way to select line (this work only for standalone expression but better than mouse)?
3. Extracting field:
   Any way to extract field in more convenient way than perform 2. followed by another magic - convert variable to field?

I'm doing mentioned combos every 1-5 minute, and it seems to me like editor completely unusable for serious work. (Iff one is not `Ray Manzarek`)How are you typing in Eclipse? Note that I prefer default settings, no fine-tuning which stops working after first upgrade or terminal change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, here's how I do:

```
DateF<ctrl-space><Enter> df = new SDF<ctrl-space><Enter>
```

For your second problem, I simply select the text I want with ctrl-shift-left_or_right_arrow.

For your third problem, no idea. I don't remember having transformed a local variable into a field for a long long time. Maybe I just know beforehand which fields I'll need for a given class.

Comment: "SDF-based" solution seems reasonable, maybe with some Ctrl+T help it can replace my idea on context-aware Ctrl+Space assist. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, I find I just need to type `DateF` <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> `df = new Sim` <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> `;`, which doesn't seem too bad to me.

For your second question <kbd>Shift-Option-Right</kbd> extends the selection to the right one word at a time, and <kbd>Shift-Option-Left</kbd> to the left; that, in combination with the keyboard shortcut you mention, should do what you want (those are Mac keys, of course, but I'm sure there are Windows equivalents; I understand some folks actually develop software on Windows.)

For number three: don't think so. You could write your own plugin to do it pretty easily.

Comment: I don't undestand the "new Sim + Enter" proposal. It does simply Sim + new line for me. I think I'm missing something, are there some floating content assist or "Sim" has to be typed directly into editor pane? Note that I'm not using Mac (nor Win).

Comment: `ALT+SHIFT+UP` can be used as well, it selects the enclosing statement not just word.